# Usage of interrobang (?!) in Japanese

Tags: punctuation

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_CbRBZhiho) when I noticed that ?! was used in the top right corner of the screen. This [interrobang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang) is regarded as poor style in English. How about in Japanese? It appears to me that it's more commonly used in Japanese than in English. (I even told one Japanese that I find using ?! a bit offensive because it's like forcing an answer out of someone.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!?` is much more common than `?!` in Japanese literature (see [!?](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%21%3F) in nicopedia), although many laypeople do not care about the order. It is not very common in serious novels, but some old novels like [蟹工船](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000156/files/1465_16805.html) have many `!?`'s. It is very common in manga and light novels today, and there we even see `!!??`, `!!!!!?` and so on. I think `!?` in a news ticker is acceptable because the space is very limited, but conservative media like NHK may use it less often. It can be offensive, but `!` by itself can be equally offensive when used in an inappropriate situation. The "ligature" interrobang symbol (‽) is almost never used in Japanese.